# Python csv read & write quotes within a string

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to automate a task involving csv files. I want to put the data from one csv with variable format (one or more columns and no quotation) to another with a fixed format (every field is surrounded by double quotes even when empty and a fixed number of columns).

I already have a script that works the way I want, but when testing the script with a real csv that contains a row with a field that contains a single quote within the string, that's when I have problems:

Sample of data received:

```
R'lyehian,lovecraft
```

What I want:

```
"R'lyehian","lovecraft"
```

the code I have right now:

```py
def csv_mover(csv_in_file, csv_out_file):
    with open(csv_in_file) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
        next(csv_reader) #Ignore the header
        with open(csv_out_file, mode = 'w', newline = '') as output_file:
            write = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter = ',', quotechar="\'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
       write.writerow([header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7,header8,header9,header10,header11])
            for row in csv_reader:
                field1 = '\"'+str(row[0])+'\"'
                field2 = '\"\"'
                field3 = '\"\"'
                field4 = '\"'+str(row[1])+'\"'
                field5 = '\"\"'
                field6 = '\"\"'
                field7 = '\"\"'
                field8 = '\"\"'
                field9 = '\"\"'
                field10 = '\"\"'
                field11 = '\"\"'
                write.writerow([field1,field,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11])
```

I already have in the csv.writer the options quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE to properly enclose the data in double quotes.

I've tried the following: Modifying the input file with single quotes around the single quote, putting an escapechar as well and modifying the csv_reader with the parameters **escapechar='\'**, **quotechar='''** but all I get is **Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set**

Solution courtesy of @Jesse

```
def csv_mover(csv_in_file, csv_out_file):
    with open(csv_in_file) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
        next(csv_reader) #Ignore the header
        with open(csv_out_file, mode = 'w', newline = '') as output_file:
            write = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter = ',', quotechar="\"", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL**strong text**)
       write.writerow([header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7,header8,header9,header10,header11])
            for row in csv_reader:
                field1 = str(row[0])
                field2 = ''
                field3 = ''
                field4 = str(row[1])
                field5 = ''
                field6 = ''
                field7 = ''
                field8 = ''
                field9 = ''
                field10 = ''
                field11 = ''
                write.writerow([field1,field,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11])
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you said you want it to return a csv where all fields are double quoted, but you're using a single quote and then telling it to never use quotes. If you use a double quote as the quotechar and use `csv.QUOTE_ALL` you can make the empty fields just be a blank string, and you don't have to worry about any manual quoting.

Comment: I've done the changes in that bit and it did the trick! Posting the solution below. Thank you!